# How are callbacks stored when it comes to curried methods?

Tags: javascript

Suppose the following code devoted to just visualise my question:

```
const handleEvent = ({ eventName }) => (data) => {
    // do stuff
}

const invokeEvent = {
    on: (event, cb) => {
        // do other stuff
        cb({ hello: 'world' })
    }
}
```

```
invokeEvent.on('test', handleEvent({ eventName: 'test' })
```

`handleEvent` is a function that returns a function (i.e. 'curried' method?). How does this *really* work under the hood? How is this callback stored and how is it then later called with `on`?

Comment: it's probably stored just like any variable - when it's passed anonymously as an argument to another function, it's like any other object ref that gets passed

Answer (score 0):

When a function is created and returned from another function (like `handleEvent` does), it also retains access to the outer function's variables, even after the outer function has completed execution. This is due to closures in JavaScript.

In your example, the returned function `(data) => { // do stuff }` has access to the `eventName` variable from the outer `handleEvent` function, thanks to closures. This allows the inner function to use `eventName` whenever it gets called, even if it's long after `handleEvent` has finished executing.

Here's a step-by-step breakdown of what happens:

1. You call `handleEvent({ eventName: 'test' })`.
2. This returns a new function `(data) => { // do stuff }` that remembers `eventName` is `'test'`.
3. You then pass this returned function as the second argument to `invokeEvent.on`.
4. Inside `invokeEvent.on`, this function is referred to by the variable `cb`.
5. You invoke the `cb` function with `{ hello: 'world' }` as its argument.
6. The function `(data) => { // do stuff }` runs with `data` being `{ hello: 'world' }` and still has access to `eventName` being `'test'`.